# Module for Tarantool, build error

Tags: c, lua, tarantool

I try write my module for tarantool:
https://github.com/agent-0007/mrasender

When i try compile it, i get error message:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found TARANTOOL: /usr/include (found version "1.6.8-611-g944d005") 
-- Tarantool LUADIR is share/tarantool
-- Tarantool LIBDIR is lib64/tarantool
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find MsgPuck (missing: MSGPUCK_INCLUDE_DIR MSGPUCK_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  FindMsgPuck.cmake:13 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: `What's wrong ?` It cannot find MsgPuck.

Comment: What I need to do for get MsgPuck ?

Comment: You could just bundle `msgpuck.h` with your sources, then you wouldn't have to find it! You can get it from https://github.com/rtsisyk/msgpuck